# My date countdown will not update

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want  to get todays time, add 10 minutes onto this and display the 10 minutes counting down in a label to the saved time.

```
-(void)updateCountdown {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"]; //Format minutes and seconds

NSDate *startingDate = [NSDate date]; //Get todays date/time right now
NSDate *endingDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600]; //Add 600 seconds     / 10 mins to it

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;


//I thought this would keep updating until the startingDate reached the same time as endingDate????
NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

//Get the minutes and seconds
NSInteger minutes = [dateComponants minute];
NSInteger seconds = [dateComponants second];

//Put mins and seconds into a string
NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Minute %d Seconds", minutes, seconds];
timeLabel.text = countdownText; //Set my label as the string
[self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; //Keep updating }
```

At the moment the label displays "10 minutes 00 seconds", but does not count down.

What I want is to count down from the starting date to the ending date:
e.g

startingDate = 12:00
endingDate = 12:10

the label will the display the difference starting at 10 mins until startingDate is 12:10

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: That's because you set `endingDate` to be "now plus 10 minutes" everytime you call this method.  You want `endingDate` to be an instance variable of your class so it will exist outside the scope of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `endingDate` and `startingDate` every time this method is called, meaning that it is re-created every second. You need to need to make it an instance variable of your class so that it is preserved across different executions of the method. For example:

```
@property (strong) NSDate *endingDate;
@property (strong) NSDatd *startingDate;
```

And then your methods would be:

```
-(id)init {

*startingDate = [NSDate date]; //Get todays date/time right now
*endingDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600]; //Add 600 seconds     / 10 mins to it

...

}

-(void)updateCountdown {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"]; //Format minutes and seconds

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;


//I thought this would keep updating until the startingDate reached the same time as endingDate????
NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

//Get the minutes and seconds
NSInteger minutes = [dateComponants minute];
NSInteger seconds = [dateComponants second];

//Put mins and seconds into a string
NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Minute %d Seconds", minutes, seconds];
timeLabel.text = countdownText; //Set my label as the string
[self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; //Keep updating }
```

That should do it.

Comment: You could probably make that date formatter an instance variable too, given its constant re-use.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!
When I put the instance variables in the init method, I get the error
"NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: fromDate cannot be nil"
It seems that it's not actually initialising the dates??

Comment: @user3739958 Are you instantiating `fromDate` properly in the `init` method?

Comment: Nope, it's just in the updateCountdown method, should it be in, init?

Comment: You must initialize the properties `startingDate` and `endingDate` in `init`, yes.

Comment: I have done but it is still throwing the error, any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem has been fixed now. My init wasn't being called!

Comment: Also, I would make the date formatter an instance variable as well, like with `startingDate` and `endingDate`. Formatters of any kind are *extremely* expensive to create.